# boolean function not working

Tags: c++, arrays, function, boolean

I'm wondering if the logic is right for this. The function gets paased an array of lets say 1,2,3,4,5 through compcards[] and also a number a user would input such as 4. however if the user guessed lets say 6 it would return false. I want to ask the user five times to guess the numbers stored in compcards[]. I'm wondering if my if else statements would make sense in this situation?

```
bool checkIfCorrect(int checkcard, int compcards[]){
    for ( int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if(compcards[i] == checkcard)
            cout<<"correct"<< endl;
        return true;    
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would only return a value from a function or print something to the screen, avoid doing both.

Comment: Sorry, don't really understand too well. What is the purpose of the array "compcards"? what does it hold? the user input or the correct answers?

Comment: this might also be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090901/c-array-value-matching-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function as below,

```
bool checkIfCorrect(int checkcard, int compcards[]){
    for ( int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        if(compcards[i] == checkcard)
        {       
            cout<<"correct"<< endl;
            return true;    
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When the 2 cards are equal, you will `return true` (after print out `"correct"`). Here you have to include the `return` statement into the `if` condition.